# pre-determine optimal level of zoom in folium

Tags: python, geolocation, zooming, folium

I am plotting some maps using folium.
Works pretty smoothly.
However, I could not figure out how to pre-calculate the right level of zoom

I can set it automatically

```
import folium
m = folium.Map([point_of_interest.iloc[0].Lat, point_of_interest.iloc[0].Long])
```

but in my use case I would need to pre-calculate  `zoom_start` such that:

- all couples `(Lat,Long)` from my `pandas` dataframe of `point_of_interest` are within the map
- the zoom level is the mnimum possilbe

Answer (score 24, accepted):

folium's [fit_bounds](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html#folium.folium.Map.fit_bounds) method should work for you

Some random sample data

```
import folium
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

center_point = [40, -90]

data = (
    np.random.normal(size=(100, 2)) *
    np.array([[.5, .5]]) +
    np.array([center_point])
)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Lat', 'Long'])
```

Creating a map with some markers

```
m = folium.Map(df[['Lat', 'Long']].mean().values.tolist())

for lat, lon in zip(df['Lat'], df['Long']):
    folium.Marker([lat, lon]).add_to(m)
```

`fit_bounds` requires the 'bounds' of our data in the form of the southwest and northeast corners.  There are some padding parameters you can use as well

```
sw = df[['Lat', 'Long']].min().values.tolist()
ne = df[['Lat', 'Long']].max().values.tolist()

m.fit_bounds([sw, ne]) 
m
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic. I have been looking for this for long time. As far as you known does osm use the same level of zoom convention as google maps?

Comment: Good deal.  Not sure on the OSM vs Google zoom levels